# Unit Testing Azure Mobile .NET Controller with Authorization

Tags: c#, unit-testing, owin, azure-mobile-services

I try to unit test my api controller with authorization in Azure Mobile App .Net Server.

My controller method looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
public HttpResponseMessage SomeMethod()
{  
    var claimsPrincipal = this.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
    string userId = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, userId);
}
```

I configured my request in unit test method like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeMyAPIControllerTest(){
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:50268/api/MyAPI");
    request.Headers.Add("x-zumo-auth", "_user_auth_token_");
    request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = config;
    var controller = new MyAPIController(TestContext)
    {
        Request = request
    };
    var response = controller.SomeMethod();
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}
```

My controller method works fine via swagger on localhost, but via unittest method it does not work. 
When I try to retrieve authenticated user information, `claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)` returns `null`

I guess there is a mistake in request configuration. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your test you can set the `User` directly on the `ApiController`.

Update your test method to create a fake user for the controller.

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeMyAPIControllerTest(){
    // Arrange
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:50268/api/MyAPI");
    request.Headers.Add("x-zumo-auth", "_user_auth_token_");
    request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = config;
    //Create test user
    var username = "username@example.com";
    var identity = new GenericIdentity(username, "");
    //Add fake claim for test
    var nameIdentifierClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username);
    identity.AddClaim(nameIdentifierClaim);
    var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles: new string[] { });
    var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(principal);
    // Set the User on the controller directly
    var controller = new MyAPIController(TestContext)
    {
        Configuration = config,
        Request = request,
        User = user
    };

    //Act
    var response = controller.SomeMethod();

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}
```